# Unable to create a self signed Certificate for SQL Server 2017(14.x.xxxx)

Tags: sql-server, powershell, certificate

Using SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition

[image: SelfSigned Cert Error]

The command I'm using is:

> New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -DnsName host.doman.com -KeySpec KeyExchange -FriendlyName SQLCert

The error message is:

> New-SelfSignedCertificate : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'KeySpec'.

My powerShell version is:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $PSversionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.18773
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Comment: Do you have spelling mistake in `host.domain.com`?

Comment: well yes that was I typo but still the error is same.

Comment: Can you try this commans? `New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My -DnsName host.domain.com -KeySpec KeyExchange -FriendlyName SQLCert`

Comment: Tried still the same error!

Comment: Try wrapping the cert store location in quotes: `New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" -DnsName host.doman.com -KeySpec KeyExchange -FriendlyName SQLCert`

Comment: Sure let me give it a try? Is there any tool(GUI'd) to perform this task. I have heard this tool named "Makecert.exe", anyone used it here?

Comment: What's the output of `get-help new-selfsignedcertificate`, does it show that parameter in the version you have?

Comment: The parameter is valid. He has to put double quotes around the domain name, CertStoreLocation, and FriendlyName. This will eliminate the (misleading) error message.

Comment: Older versions of PowerShell didn't support the -KeySpec parameter for New-SelfSignedCertificate.  I am unsure of exactly when this parameter was added, but I do know it was not present in Server 2012 or 2012 R2, but is available in Windows 10 and Server 2016.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose CertStoreLocation, Subject, DnsName and FriendlyName with double quotes.

There is no need to specify a location as it will default to "Local Computer/Personal/Certificates" where it needs to be in order to use it by SQL Server.

This will generate a valid certificate on Windows Server 2016 that will be usable by SQL Server 2017:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=insert FQDN here" -DnsName "<insert FQDN here>","insert NetBIOS name here" -FriendlyName "Self Signed Certificate Friendly Name" -KeySpec KeyExchange -KeyLength 2048 -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(5)
```

Please replace 'insert FQDN here' and 'insert NetBIOS name here' with the actual FQDN and NetBIOS name keeping the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days I manged to Setup a connection locally with my SQL Server 2017.
Here what I did, I know its not a good approach but some how worked for me!

1. Added Inbound *New Rule* for port 1433(Both TCP and UDP)
2. Added outbound *New Rule* for port 1433(Both TCP and UDP)
3. Allowed my client application in my case its Android Studio in the firewall.
4. Tested with my Android app now no SSL required.

[image: Screenshot of Windows showing a successful test connection]